# Chrome thinks new panel is popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, popup

I have a problem which appears only in Google Chrome. When user clicked on button, ajax called script which takes little bit longer (about 2 seconds) to execute. After this time it should open a new tab with certain page. But only google chrome thinks this is a popup and this problem is only in this script, if takes little bit longer. When I try this steps in localhost, it takes only about 0.5 sec and page is opened in new tab. But when i put my code  to production server, there is bigger db traffic, so the script is executing longer and chrome thinks that is popup. In my opinion, there is some time setting in chrome and after the time chrome thinks everything is popup...

Can anybody help me how can i avoid chrome thinks this is popup?

Thanks for any advices.

Code:

```
    function checkStatus(url, urlToCheck) {
        var solved = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: urlToCheck,
            context: document.body,
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 0) {
                    solved = false;
                }
            }
        });

        if (!solved) {
            window.open(url);
        } else {
            var r = confirm('Send e-mail?');
            if (r == true) {
               window.open(url);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Don't use `async: false` and put your `if` condition inside the `success` handler.

Comment: When i do this, every browser thinks the new page is popup. I've found this solution in stackoverflow.

Comment: but when i put my `if` condition into succes handler, everything seems to be ok, but i have to have `assync:false`